# Extjs Image/png from ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, image, extjs

Hi there I am working on an application which displays dynamically generated images on a server. To fetch the image, png in our case, the application uses an Ajax Request. The retrieved data looks like this:

```
    "�PNG


    IHDRLXx�s
    sBIT|d� pHYsaa�?�i IDATx���w|U�����~�{BI(�H/�4AaeQQp�>�n�]Wݯ�"�W?~t���uuW]�""R)RBI ����w~�;)7   Iя�.................................
..........................................."
```

which looks like [this](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html):

In my application I have a Text:image where I want to display the image, but i don't know how to do it. Does anyone know how?

Here goes the ajax request code.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
url: 'http://localhost/my_url/you_dont_need_to_know_this',
success: function(response){                
    //img.setData(response.responseText); //img is a Ext:image component.
    debugger;
},
scope: this
```

});

Comment: what does your ajax request look like..? Can you show us your code pls...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if your server responsds with image data, do something like,

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    binary: true,  //set binary to true
    url: 'http://localhost/my_url/you_dont_need_to_know_this',
    success: function(response) {
        var blob = new Blob([response.responseBytes], {type: 'image/png'}),
        url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob),
        img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = url;

        //do something with img
    }
});
```